# Burying a buffer shows an already displayed buffer

Tags: buffers, window

ISTR that [`quit-window`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quitting-Windows.html) and [`bury-buffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-List.html) made sure that the replacement/newly displayed buffer is not shown in any other window (at least that was my intention when I wrote [`quit-window`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quitting-Windows.html) many years ago).

Right now I see that <kbd>C-x b</kbd> ([`switch-to-buffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Buffer.html)) offers a good candidate (IOW, [`other-buffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Switching-Buffers.html) returns a buffer that is not currently shown), but both [`quit-window`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quitting-Windows.html) and [`bury-buffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-List.html) replace the current buffer with one that is already displayed in another window in the current frame.

Is there a way to restore the original behavior of never displaying an already visible buffer?

Is this a (known) bug?

(I have no easy access to email, so, alas, I cannot easily submit an emacs bug report).

PS. `GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2023-08-02`

Postmortem: it turned out that I have been setting `switch-to-prev-buffer-skip` to `t` since forever, but only at home (where I have ~30 years worth of settings under git), while at work I was not able to bring all those settings over, and I now I have to recover them one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
(setq switch-to-prev-buffer-skip t)
```

Docstring excerpt of note:

> Since ‘switch-to-prev-buffer’ is called by ‘bury-buffer’,
> ‘replace-buffer-in-windows’ and ‘quit-restore-window’ among
> others, customizing this option may also affect the behavior of
> Emacs when a window is quit or a buffer gets buried or killed.

In full (from 29.2):

```
switch-to-prev-buffer-skip is a variable defined in ‘window.el’.

Its value is nil

Buffers ‘switch-to-prev-buffer’ should skip.
If this variable is nil, ‘switch-to-prev-buffer’ may switch to
any buffer, including those already shown in other windows.

If this variable is non-nil, ‘switch-to-prev-buffer’ will refrain
from switching to certain buffers according to the value of this
variable:

- ‘this’ means do not switch to a buffer shown on the frame that
  hosts the window ‘switch-to-prev-buffer’ is acting upon.

- ‘visible’ means do not switch to a buffer shown on any visible
  frame.

- 0 (the number zero) means do not switch to a buffer shown on
  any visible or iconified frame.

- t means do not switch to a buffer shown on any live frame.

If this option specifies a function, that function is called with
three arguments - the WINDOW argument of ‘switch-to-prev-buffer’,
a buffer ‘switch-to-prev-buffer’ intends to switch to and the
BURY-OR-KILL argument of ‘switch-to-prev-buffer’.  If that
function returns non-nil, ‘switch-to-prev-buffer’ will not switch
to that buffer.

Since ‘switch-to-prev-buffer’ is called by ‘bury-buffer’,
‘replace-buffer-in-windows’ and ‘quit-restore-window’ among
others, customizing this option may also affect the behavior of
Emacs when a window is quit or a buffer gets buried or killed.

The value of this option is consulted by ‘switch-to-next-buffer’
as well.  In that case, if this option specifies a function, it
will be called with the third argument nil.

Under certain circumstances ‘switch-to-prev-buffer’ may ignore
this option, for example, when there is only one buffer left.

Also see ‘switch-to-prev-buffer-skip-regexp’.

  This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
  version 27.1 of Emacs.
  You can customize this variable.
```